# Помогите оживить сервер в remote console

Tags: linux, centos, файловая-система

Есть выделенный сервер на hetzner с CentOs 7.8, который умер после reboot вчера ночью. Сегодня заказал в панели управления remote console (KVM). При входе в консоль получил ошибку: `error: attempt to read or write outside of disk ‘hd0’.`

Погуглил, нашёл тему https://askubuntu.com/

Выяснил, что раздел, в котором у меня находится Linux - (md/2) Вбил

```
set root=(md/2)
set prefix=(md/2)/boot/grub
```

Однако при вводе команды `insmod normal` получаю ошибку:

```
error: unknown filesystem
```

Подскажите какие шаги я могу предпринять для оживления сервера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пиши linux /boot/linux.. ..... initrd /boot/initfamfs... ....

Comment: Бесполезно, саппорт проверил и сказал, что умер винчестер